# No static method getDefaultAPIVersion al llamar a FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize

Tags: java, android, android-studio, facebook-api

He migrado un proyecto que tenía hecho hace 2 años de Eclipse a Android Studio, y al hacerlo me he dado cuenta que las clases de Facebook ya no funcionan igual. Tras migrar también las clases a la API de Facebook v4.0 y conseguir que el Android Studio no me diera ningún problema de compilación, lanzo la app en mi móvil y me da este error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.dreamseek.flyingninjapig, PID: 14375
                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDefaultAPIVersion()Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/facebook/internal/ServerProtocol; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.facebook.internal.ServerProtocol' appears in /data/data/com.dreamseek.flyingninjapig/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex)
                      at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.<clinit>(FacebookSdk.java:85)
                      at com.dreamseek.flyingninjapig.Main.onCreate(Main.java:80)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Mi método onCreate realiza lo siguiente:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    vista = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(vista);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    // gesti�n del Locale
    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources()
            .getConfiguration();

    // 1) Compruebo si en SharedPreferences hay elegido un idioma
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    lang = prefs.getString("selectedLanguage", "");

    // 2) Si no, tomo el defaultLocale de la APP
    if (lang.equals(""))
        lang = getString(R.string.defaultLocale);

    if (!"".equals(lang) && !config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
        locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }


    // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Sabéis por qué puede ser? He realizado las sustituciones del manifest que se decían en la guía de migración de facebook developers y no sé qué más puede ser. Os dejo también mi build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'iso-8859-1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dreamseek.flyingninjapig"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':baseGameUtils')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Verificaste las dependencias de tu proyecto? En dos años muchas deben haber cambiado!, actualiza tus appcompat y otras dependiencias! verifica posibles duplicaciones ya que migraste de un IDE a otro!

Comment: Hola!, sí las comprobé y actualicé a la v23 todo lo que pude en el gradle... appcompat no la tengo como dependencia en el proyecto, ¿debería? ¿cuál es su utilidad? El proyecto se compila y se instala bien el APK en el móvil, el problema es al lanzarlo, que da la excepción que puse arriba

Comment: De hecho si quito la integración con FB el proyecto arranca perfectamente en el móvil :(

Comment: Me parecia que podia ir por ahi el problema! Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Solucionado!!!
Cuando me traje el proyecto desde ADT me incorporó COMO MÓDULO una librería de facebook. Aunque la eliminé de los módulos, algo debió quedarse en los datos generados por Android Studio.
He hecho un clean project y un rebuild y ahora va de perlas.
Saludos!

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas podido solventar, no olvides en marcarte como respuesta correcta, de aquí unas horas te dejará marcarla